# Is there any way to get the dart editor to always run the same command?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I always wanted Cmd-r to "Run my main.html" file.

Is there any way to do this. Currently, when I look at the Eclipse XML output of my keybindings, it appears that Cmd-r is bound to "Run". This is fine in general, but it is annoying because I have to always switch out of any .html file I am currently editing and open main.html before I press Cmd-r.

I am on Dart Editor version 0.4.5_r21094.

Answer (score 8):

We are in the process of adding an menu option "Always run the last launch". With this option checked, once you have run the main.html, the editor will run the same launch on Cmd-r (selection no longer matters) until you explicitly launch another html file.

Answer (score 1):

[Feature has been added!](http://news.dartlang.org/2013/04/new-dart-editor-build-with-run-last-launch-option.html?utm_source=dartweekly&utm_medium=email)

> Run > Always Run Last Launch menu option when enabled will always run
>   the last launch unless user chooses another launch explicitly.